# Convert string into floating number with '+' or '-' before number

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

could someone please assist in following:
I have **string** which picked up from page and after that convert it to an **int**. It does work correct, but when I have case with following number:

```
+281.35 or -3.45
```

then I am stuck. I just want to check if number is shown (for negative value) or, in same cases to confirm that number is greater than zero. I achieve for numbers without **+** or **-** in it. So, please, help how to convert string +281.34 into decimal number. It will be much easier if I just trim **+** or **-** signs and save the number without it. Below is how did conversion and check for **int** type:

```
String number1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("some correct path")).getText();
    Thread.sleep(200);
    int numero1 = Integer.parseInt(number1);
    if (numero1 <= 0) {
        System.out.println("Not positive number. Closing test!");
        driver.close();
    }
```

Comment: `int` is no floating point number , use `float` (and `parseFloat`) instead.

Comment: @Berger thank you, it works

Comment: @Berger - only left, is how to remove + or - sign in front of number before checking ?

Comment: A `String` with a leading + or - is well interpreted by `parseFloat`, you don't need to remove the sign character .

Comment: @Berger - thanks, again